# View all the documents loaded into vespa

Tags: vespa

Is there any way to fetch all the documents loaded into vespa?

I tried querying with regular expressions, but it didn't work as expected.

`select * from entity where ID matches "[.]+";`

ID is not an attribute, but I tried with an attribute field, both didn't respond with any values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using visiting instead of search, either with the [vespa-visit](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/content/visiting.html) tool or using [visiting in the document/v1 REST API](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/document-api.html#get) is usually preferable for dumping documents.

If you want to use search, use this query to match all documents of a type:

```
select * from yourdocumenttype where sddocname contains 'yourdocumenttype';
```

To iterate over all documents with this, it will be more efficient to use a some field in your document to partition the document set into smaller chunks and query for one chunk at a time (e.g if you have a timestamp field, add a range condition to the query to retrieve documents for a slice of time in each query).

(Regular expressions are only supported in streaming mode.)

Answer (score 3):

To dump all documents from Vespa, use [vespa-visit](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/content/visiting.html):

"visit" is a different interface than the search interface - it is built for large data transfers with high throughput, but not necessarily low latency

Teams use visit to extract a full dump or a subset, using a [selection expression](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/document-select-language.html)